# Detect Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to detect Yoast SEO. I already use this function:

```
function active( $plugin ) {
    $network_active = false;
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        $plugins = get_site_option( 'active_sitewide_plugins' );
        if ( isset( $plugins[$plugin] ) ) {
            $network_active = true;
        }
    }
    return in_array( $plugin, get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) || $network_active;
}

if ( active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) {
```

And that works fine. But if Yoast ever thinks of renaming `wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php`, this function becomes useless. So we need to add an backup, something which is hard to change, like the `WPSEO_VERSION` constant:

```
if ( active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) {
    // activate
} elseif( defined( 'WPSEO_VERSION' )) {
    // activate
} else {
    // deactivate
}
```

This line `if( defined( 'WPSEO_VERSION' )) {` for some reason does not detect Yoast.. how is that possible?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: First of all, we will not rename that file.

Secondly, it is not save to check for any plugin related things without wrapping it on a `plugins_loaded` hook as Fencer04 pointed out.

The hook `plugins_loaded` is triggered whenever all plugins are loaded, thus all constants and classes exist. Plugins are loaded in an order which can not be relied upon, it's not alphabetically. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded - Hope this helps, Jip from Yoast.

Comment: did you found the answer @hacked files

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is:

```
if ( 
    is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) 
    || is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo-premium/wp-seo-premium.php' )
) {
   /* Let's do cool things */
}
```

[Function Reference/is plugin active](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active)

Answer (score 6):

This is as safe you can get:

```
if(in_array('wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))){ 
    /* Yoast is active */
}
```

And I would also suggest:

```
if(class_exists('WPSEO_Options')){
    /* Yoast is active */
    if(WPSEO_Options::get('breadcrumbs-enable', false)){
        /* Yoast breadcrumbs is active */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is probably checking WPSEO_VERSION before YOAST is loaded. Try using one of the following hooks to run the function that checks the WPSEO_VERSION constant.

```
add_action('init', 'active');

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'active');
```

Comment: I have tried working with the provided code but can't seem to understand how to get it working. Can you maybe provide an example?

Comment: If you put your whole functions file on gist.com I'll review it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple method to detect it be the `<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->` that Yoast adds in the source code, you can find it and if it's there, you got it. For example, here is a [site](https://www.onlinetoolsexpert.com/) that you can see in its source code.